# Haskell: deriving Show for Fix types

Tags: haskell, typeclass, deriving, fixpoint-combinators

I'm trying to implement a recursive datatype using `recursion-schemes`. I would like to be able to print it.

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data T1F a = Foo deriving Show
type T1 = Fix T1F
data T2 = Bar T1 deriving Show -- error here
```

Error message:

```
No instance for (Data.Functor.Classes.Show1 T1F)
  arising from the first field of ‘Bar’ (type ‘T1’)
Possible fix:
  use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
    so you can specify the instance context yourself
When deriving the instance for (Show T2)
```

How do I make `T1` derive `Show`?

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. You need an instance of [`Show1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Show1) for `T1F`. Writing instances of `Show1` by hand can be quite tedious. Fortunately the [`deriving-compat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-compat) package [has got your back](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-compat-0.3.5/docs/Text-Show-Deriving.html#v:deriveShow1).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson is there an example of deriving it manually?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Easiest way is to derive `Show` for your datatype, look at the generated code by compiling with `-ddump-deriv`, and then paste and adapt it. Not a fun task, though - much easier to use the TH helpers in the pkg!

Comment: I see. I still don't understand why this is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the package `deriving-compat`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Text.Show.Deriving

data T1F a = Foo deriving Show
$(deriveShow1 ''T1F)
type T1 = Fix T1F
data T2 = Bar T1 deriving Show
```